# Program to find the occurrence of a word in string using for loop?

Tags: python, list

I have written this code in python to count the number of occurrence of each word in python. I just want to do that using `for` loop. No other inbuilt datatype like sets or dictionary. I think I have done wrong indentation.

```
mystring="Virat plays cricket. Virat is a batsman."
mylist=mystring.split(' ')
j=0
#the i outer loop that will iterate each element in list
for i in range(0,len(mylist)):
count=1
'''the j loop is to check whether value at j has occurred previously or not,
Like Virat at index 3 has occured previously also at index 0, so it should
not count that and it should break the loop because virat has counted previously
'''
for j in range(i-1,-1,-1):
    if mylist[i]==mylist[j]:
        break
if j==-1:
      '''if a word hasn't founded previously then it should start iterating
      next element from mylist[i]'''
      for j in range(i+1,len(mylist)):
        if mylist[i]==mylist[j]:
          count=count+1
print(mylist[i]," has occured ",count)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What makes you think you have a wrong indentation ? Do you have an error ?

Comment: My question was to count the occurence of each word in a sentence. If the word has already counted earlier, then it should not get counted again.

Thanks everyone for the help. I Solved the question. I did two small changes
1- first j loop will run till -1, in above question it was only running till 0.
2- last print statement will indented inside if j==-1 block. 

Thanks everyone. If you guys can upvote this question, then it would be great.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's way easier than this.

```
word = "tree"
phrase = "We must count how many times the word tree is included in this phrase. If I write tree again, then it's two"
counter = phrase.count(word)
print(f"The word {word} appears {counter} times")
```

And the output will, of course, be `2`.
I suggest you to learn writing posts on Stackoverflow if you want to avoid downvotes. I also suggest you to only use `#` comments and not multiline strings and browsing a little bit more before asking for help. I admit I didn't know there was a direct way to do this task, but a fast research did the trick.

Edit: if you're looking for a manual check, you can try out this:

```
word_to_check = "tree"
counter = 0
phrase = "We must count how many times the word tree is included in this phrase. If I write tree again, then it's two"
phrase_array = phrase.split(" ")
for word in phrase_array:
    if word == word_to_check:
        counter = counter + 1
print(f"The word {word} appears {counter} times")
```

Comment: I wasn't looking for the count of specific word, I was looking for the count of every word in a string. I did good research before asking here. As I am very new in python, So that's why I asked here. Anyway Thanks for the help. I solved the question now.

Comment: good to know. sorry for being rough, but the question wans't well explained.

Comment: I am new to Stack Overflow. i will try to explain the question in depth from next time.

Comment: it's not a problem, nobody can do anything perfectly at the first time